# Rails Redirect_path after save based on view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have two views (`new.html.erb` and `retirement_accounts_new.html.erb`) in the `Accounts` both using the same create and update methods.

Here's how they're defined in the controller:

```
  # GET /accounts/new
  def new
    @account = current_user.accounts.build
  end

  # GET /retirement/accounts/new
  def retirement_accounts_new
    @account = current_user.accounts.build
  end
```

And here's the same create method they share:

```
  def create
    @account = current_user.accounts.build(account_params)
    if @account.save
      redirect_to accounts_path, notice: 'Account was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end
```

Is there a way to make that `redirect_to accounts_path` conditional based on which view is rendering the form?

I would like `retirement_accounts_new` on save/update to `redirect_to retirement_accounts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this might be a design issue. Are `Accounts` and `RetirementAccounts` significantly different? Will they share much of the same logic, but not all? If so, I think I would avoid using conditional logic in the controller and solve it using inheritance.

The idea here is that `retirement_accounts` would be considered a new resource in your routes file:

```
resources :retirement_accounts
```

Then you manually create a new controller for it (skip the `rails generate...` command). Save this file as `app/controllers/retirement_accounts_controller.rb`:

```
class RetirementAccountsController < AccountsController
end
```

Notice how it inherits from `AccountsController` instead of `ApplicationController`. Even in this empty state, `RetirementAccountsController` shares all of the logic of `AccountsController`, including the `new` and `create` methods, plus all of the view files to which they refer. To make the necessary modifications for the retirement accounts, you simply need to override the appropriate actions and views.

You can delete your `retirement_accounts_new` action, since it is identical to the `new` action. Move the view for `retirement_accounts_new` to `app/views/retirement_accounts/new.html.erb`, so that template will be rendered when `new` is called on the `RetirementAccountsController`.

As for the conditional create method, you can make a private method on both controllers that will determine where the post-create redirect should point:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def create
    @account = current_user.accounts.build(account_params)
    if @account.save
      redirect_to post_create_redirect_path, notice: 'Account was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def post_create_redirect_path
    accounts_path
  end
end

class RetirementAccountsController < AccountsController

  private

  def post_create_redirect_path
     retirement_accounts_path
  end
end
```

Comment: This is perfect & well explained. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If `RetirementAccount < Account` as a single table inheritance model then the thing you are asking would happen by default,

plan B would be to use explicit `url_for` in the redirect such as:

```
redirect_to url_for(controller: params[:controller], action: :show, id: @account.id), notice: 'Account was successfully created.'
```

Looking at the api doc this should work too:

```
redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @account.id,notice: 'Account was successfully created.'
```

Check out http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to - there's probably an answer for you there somewhere :)

---

PS I have assumed that the the retirement account and account actions are in different controllers. If they're not in different controllers and not different model classes then you can put a hidden tag in the `new` form - but this is bad&ugly

Best solution is probably STI model and 2 separate resources for the 2 classes and everything will work out of the box. If this isn't an option, at least separate the controllers and make things clean that way, it's much better to reuse views then to reuse controllers